# Using external data with views in drupal

Tags: view, drupal-6

I have an external database that obviously is storing some data. I am setting up a "monitoring" page that grabs data and displays it in a table format with the most recent inserted values. i have already written a module that displays this data (getting the data and theming it by hand so to speak). The current setup is nice but i wanted to attempt to integrate this data with views. i came across the data module but it appears that i would need to get data into the drupal database. although that is easy, it just doesn't make sense to copy data from one repo to another repo.

Is there a way to get external data to integrate with views nicely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are facing the same problem that was mentioned before . read this article it may helps you [How to publish data residing in an external database using Drupal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918849/drupal-accessing-external-database)

All i know is you can connect drupal with other external database .

Comment: Yea. I eventually figured out what i need to do. essentially just connected to the database. no need to move data. all is good with the world. thanks for the response.